# Application for finding song names

Tags: software-recommendation, music

I'd like to know if anyone knows an application or knows of one being developed that can do what I've stated in the question. On mobile devices there's an App called [Shazam](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shazam.android): Is there an equivalent for this on the Ubuntu desktop?

It'd be really useful as I've several times heard songs online or on TV with no lyrics (so I can't just google them) and I'm left with no idea as to what the name of the music track could be even though they're catchy tunes.

To explain in a clearer way: I'm looking for an application that "listens" to the song playing on your PC for a few seconds and gives you the name of the song using an internet database. If there's a plugin which does this in a media player such as [Banshee](http://banshee.fm/), [Rhythmbox](http://projects.gnome.org/rhythmbox/index.html) or any other which works on Ubuntu, feel free to point it out as well.

Comment: midomi.com works

Comment: @function thanks for the site, it works perfectly, but I'd prefer to have a desktop-integrated app if possible.

Comment: midomi.com was the successor of soundhound.com for which it seems not to exists a desktop app.

Answer (score 1):

Another website which works: http://www.audiotag.info

Would prefer an desktop application, too :)

Comment: I've tested the webapp and indeed it was right, but I had to upload the whole song (12MB) which is very uncomfty for big audio databases. But if you need just one song identified it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to try [nightingale](http://getnightingale.com/) which is a new cross platform music player. It gives you many information (using WWW) for the tracks playing (either from MP3 or from online radio stations) and it comes with a fair collection of [add-ons](http://wiki.getnightingale.com/doku.php?id=add-ons).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately didn't find an Add-On which suited my needs, though a very nice media player indeed, highly customizable!

Comment: Does Nightingale "listen" to music and look up the song using an online dictionary? If not, I don't see how this answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use song identification shell script (https://github.com/kukulo2011/Song_identification), which works with echoprint-codegen song identification software and Mooma.sh API service. You just have to download, setup, request API key and use the service.