# What application do the same what shazam or soundhound does on android?

Tags: sound, search, mp3, mp3-player

What application do the same what [shazam](http://www.shazam.com/music/web/getshazam.html) or [soundhound](http://www.soundhound.com/) does on android?

[Shazam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shazam_%28service%29) for windows and MacOs, I don't like wine, plus it is commercial. You can verify about 2-5 songs and must pay to continue.

[SoundHound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SoundHound) - closely mobile Os's app.

What kind of application for Linux/Ubuntu can do the same?

```
$ soundhound song.mp3
The Beatles - Let it be - imdb index#
```

I found this question but answers are about mp3 tag only:
[Application for finding song names](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235658/application-for-finding-song-names)

Answer (score 4):

OK so it is a little bit of a hack.

First go to:

1. [Directly to the flash program on the Midomi site](http://www.midomi.com/objects/midomiLandingVoiceSearch.swf)

   This will be annoying probably because you cant click on the accept microphone button because adobe is annoying. Using <kbd>Tab</kbd> you can move around but it still doesn't seem to let you allow with <kbd>Enter</kbd>. So enter on the "?". Adobe flash player has seen you have interacted with this dialogue.
2. [Now go to the settings manager page of the Adobe site](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager06.html)

   The picture is not a picture but settings. This one works and you can tell it to always allow midomi. This should be here because of using midomi before. (If not play with the stupid broken dialoge on the midomi site 1-2 more times then restart firefox). Once you have selected Allow for midomi on the Adobe page restart firefox and fo back to the flash program and it should work!

Answer (score 4):

[SongRec](https://github.com/marin-m/SongRec) is an application that makes use of the Shazam song identification algorithm to identify songs on the Linux desktop. It can identify songs either using the microphone or by providing an audio file.

It works both with a GUI and from the command line. Although from the command line, it can only identify songs from an audio file, like this:

```
songrec audio-file-to-recognized-song /path/to/song.mp3
```

[Source](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2020/10/identify-songs-on-your-linux-desktop.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can use Shazam for android with Archon Runtime and Google Chrome

http://archon-runtime.github.io/

1. Download and install Shazam to your android device
2. Export Shazam apk with Archon packager (install from google play)
   https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.bpear.archonpackager&hl=de
3. Download Archon Runtime 2.1 Beta and Google Chrome Browser
4. Enable Developer mode in Google chrome browser
5. Extract Archon and downloaded Apk.zip
6. Load Archon and Shazam as unpacked extension
7. search the Shazam in the Dash and run the application

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use Shazam on Linux with a virtual machine with Android x86 in it and the Shazam App. I created a little video that shows the installation process and the usage:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2S2sWBTVPu8

Answer (score 1):

I needed Shazam like services on my music server. I did not want a desktop application in order to run music detection from command line. 
With this project, you can detect current played sound :
[Shazam on linux](https://github.com/Lahorde/shazam-on-linux)

Answer (score 1):

Just discovered MusicBrainz Picard, you can just easily install it with `sudo apt-get install picard`. It creates an audio ID of your song and looks it up in a database, did help me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I just uploaded [zhavam to github](https://github.com/ipserc/zhavam). It uses ACR Cloud to retrieve the song facts of the music you’re reproducing in your Linux box.

The only thing you need is to create a free account on ACR Cloud and put your access data in `zhavan.conf`. You can use the config editor of zhavam to do this.

To run zhavam you need to put `libacrcloud_recognizer.so` in your system and update `ldconf` or use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/acrcloud`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using https://www.aha-music.com/ from a web browser.